# Is there a way to get the data from multiple selects as array?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm currently stuck on a task on VueJS. Basically I'm trying to create an array from multiple `select` inside a form to get all the data as an array or Object to process it further. I just searched but got no results or an idea on how to solve my issue.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <div id="product" class="mt-12">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap mb-4">
            <div class="w-1/2 pr-12">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/800" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="w-1/2">

                <div class="flex justify-between content-center h-12 mb-4">
                    <div class="text-gray-700 py-2">
                        <h2 v-if="product.brand" class="leading-none font-bold text-sm">{{ product.brand }}</h2>
                        <h1 class="text-xl leading-snug">{{ product.name }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-gray-700 py-2">
                        <p class="text-xl font-bold leading-none">{{ product.price }}</p>
                        <p class="text-xs text-right leading-none">Inkl. 19% MwSt.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="divider bg-gray-400 mt-4 mb-4" />

                <div id="variations">
                    <form action="">
                        <ProductVariation v-for="(variations, type) in product.variations" :type="type" :variations="variations" :key="type" v-model="form.variation"/>

                        <div class="flex w-full">
                            <button class="w-full leading-none bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white py-2 rounded" type="submit">Add to cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import ProductVariation from '@/components/products/ProductVariation'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            product: null,
            form: {
                variation: null
            }
        }
    },

    components: {
        ProductVariation
    },

    async asyncData({ params, app }) {
        let response = await app.$axios.$get(`products/${params.slug}`)

        return {
            product: response.data
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ProductVariation Component**

```
<template>

        <div class="flex mb-4">
            <div class="w-full">
                <label class="block text-gray-700 w-full text-sm font-bold">{{ type }}</label>
                <select class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight" :name="type">
                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option v-for="variation in variations" :key="variation.id" :value="variation.id">{{ variation.name }} <span>( +{{ variation.price }} )</span></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        type: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        variations: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: What issues are you facing  / errors you are getting ?

Comment: That would a be a step further that im currently are. im basically completly stuck and have no clue how to achieve that i want to do

Comment: if you can create a sample here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) it will be much easier to debug your app

Comment: and btw your `asyncData` function is returning an object ... your `product` variable is still `null` this way